# Possible typo in Fourier transform exercise

Tags: fourier-analysis

The Fourier transform of a function $f(x)$ is given by

$$ \mathcal{F}(f)(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i w x} dx $$

Then, there is a problem that asks to prove that if $f$ is differentiable and the integrals for $\mathcal{F}(f)(w)$ and $\mathcal{F}(f')(w) $ converge, then

$$ \mathcal{F}(f')(w) = \frac{1}{i w} \mathcal{F}(f)(w) $$

But I get that $\mathcal{F}(f')(w) = iw \mathcal{F}(f)(w) $. Is this a typo?

Comment: It certainly looks like a typo. They've given the Fourier Transform of the integral of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo. Dividing by $iw$ corresponds to the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ integrated. For example, in control engineering an integrator block is labeled $1/s$ where $s$ is the complex frequency variable of the Laplace transform, which becomes the Fourier transform for $s = iw$. Is it a first edition book?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems

http://www.pg.gda.pl/~mkwies/dyd/geadocu/expdobbl.gif

Comment: it is the third edition of marsden basic complex analysis